# Attach files ics with cdosys and view in gmail

Tags: asp-classic, gmail, cdo.message

I'm having a problem with an attached .ics file to the email and when it is
I can do it properly but when I open the email I have an incorrect result.
If I attach the .ics file and send it via email when I open the message with gmail I will show the message preview gmail with all the information, but if I am attaching the file ics sending it to a server via object cdosys ASP me appears in an inscription in the email to go to google calendar but without having the preview

The file that I am attaching are equal, and inside of the email I can download it in the same way.

Going to see, however, the message code is known that the first (email preview) has code attached cripatato and another (email without preview) clear
![good preview][1]
![message text no preview][2]

**good code**

```
Delivered-To: pippoprovaz@gmail.com
Received: by 10.70.26.228 with SMTP id o4csp279669pdg;
    Fri, 20 Feb 2015 14:13:08 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.194.48.74 with SMTP id j10mr23601760wjn.38.1424470387690;
    Fri, 20 Feb 2015 14:13:07 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <Pippo.deProva@email.it>
Received: from emout01.email.it (emout01.email.it. [212.97.34.23])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTP id eu4si4967228wib.107.2015.02.20.14.13.06
    for <pippoprovaz@gmail.com>;
    Fri, 20 Feb 2015 14:13:07 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of Pippo.deProva@email.it designates         212.97.34.23 as permitted sender) client-ip=212.97.34.23;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of Pippo.deProva@email.it designates     212.97.34.23 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=Pippo.deProva@email.it
Received: from emout01.email.it (localhost [127.0.0.1])
by emout01.email.it (Postfix) with ESMTP id 939E8961E5
for <pippoprovaz@gmail.com>; Fri, 20 Feb 2015 23:13:05 +0100 (CET)
Received: from 78.213.240.171 (50.34.97.212.host.static.ip.kpnqwest.it [212.97.34.50])
by emout01.email.it (Postfix) with ESMTP id 462DB961E1
for <pippoprovaz@gmail.com>; Fri, 20 Feb 2015 23:13:05 +0100 (CET)
Received: from Email-mailer ([78.213.240.171]) 
by 78.213.240.171 with HTTP (Wmail);
Fri, 20 Feb 2015 23:13:27 +0100
Date: Fri, 20 Feb 2015 23:13:27 +0100
To: pippoprovaz@gmail.com
From: Pippo De Prova <Pippo.deProva@email.it>
Reply-to: Pippo De Prova <Pippo.deProva@email.it>
Subject: 
Message-ID: <595ec85d8657342b8e1ae7c8275139cc@78.213.240.171>
X-Priority: 
X-Mailer: Webmail-Email.it [Mailer version 1.70]
X-SenderIP: 78.213.240.171
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="b1_595ec85d8657342b8e1ae7c8275139cc"


--b1_595ec85d8657342b8e1ae7c8275139cc
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="b2_595ec85d8657342b8e1ae7c8275139cc"

--b2_595ec85d8657342b8e1ae7c8275139cc
Content-Type: text/plain; charset = "iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit




--b2_595ec85d8657342b8e1ae7c8275139cc--
--b1_595ec85d8657342b8e1ae7c8275139cc
Content-Type: text/calendar; name="nonVis.ics"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="nonVis.ics"
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--b1_595ec85d8657342b8e1ae7c8275139cc--
```

**no good code**

```
    Delivered-To: deProvaPippo@gmail.com
    Received: by 10.70.26.228 with SMTP id o4csp268051pdg;
    Fri, 20 Feb 2015 13:47:38 -0800 (PST)
    X-Received: by 10.50.111.168 with SMTP id ij8mr147639igb.43.1424468858565;
    Fri, 20 Feb 2015 13:47:38 -0800 (PST)
    Return-Path: <bounces+1528665-e85c-deProvaPippo=gmail.com@ssss.me>
    Received: from o1.f.az.sss.net (o1.f.az.sss.net. [])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id t17si24017808icl.78.2015.02.20.13.47.38
    for <deProvaPippo@gmail.com>
    (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
    Fri, 20 Feb 2015 13:47:38 -0800 (PST)
    Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of bounces+1528665-e85c-        deProvaPippo=gmail.com@sssss.me designates 208.117.55.132 as permitted sender) client-ip=ssss;
    Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounces+1528665-e85c-        deProvaPippo=gmail.com@ssss.me designates 208.117.55.132 as permitted sender)         smtp.mail=bounces+1528665-e85c-deProvaPippo=gmail.com@sss.me;
   dkim=pass header.i=@ssss.me
    DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed; d=ssss.me; 
h=from:to:subject:mime-version:content-type:content-transfer-encoding:list-        unsubscribe:x-feedback-id; 
s=smtpapi; bh=undMBD+qKNE1GwBLr58rPPf3HtE=; b=brSOhe4gM9ytjdpvz3
dxPTS+XUpFZIWR+Pm/gDP549JlszKm3nQOi+EJco6tfrrezqJ6IRmWec1C3hWGDW
nkHWxpU5mO4lbUJFvgb3GpfgnVEG1Lyj0ypFrZB35pYafeuI1VCMSZb2IYfDc8Z5
gAgr64ksLsp/DmawENZAW2AwI=
    Received: by filter0210p1mdw1.ssss.net with SMTP id         filter0210p1mdw1.16398.54E7AB74C
    2015-02-20 21:47:34.764937675 +0000 UTC
    Received: from RD000D3A206CCE (unknown [10.68.181.194])
by ismtpd-001 (SG) with ESMTP id 14ba8f5c6f0.1d81.486682
for <deProvaPippo@gmail.com>; Fri, 20 Feb 2015 21:47:34 +0000 (UTC)
    thread-index: AdBNVtVC+8xyMDrUQMeO/WOGpGp00A==
    Thread-Topic: Service RDV BabySitter
    From: <info@gmail.com>
    To: <deProvaPippo@gmail.com>
    Subject: ServeXia RDV BabySitter
    Date: Fri, 20 Feb 2015 21:47:33 -0000
    Message-ID: <7CA8363974F84ACEAB51BABEB33A2143@RD000D3A206CCE>
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
name="invite.ics"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="invite.ics"
    X-Mailer: Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000
    Content-Class: urn:content-classes:message
    Importance: normal
    Priority: normal
    X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.2.9200.16384
    X-SG-EID:                         asLfHF183T/r3z5aDu8bv6Sekqs8eKacpuWFbt+jsTEG1Cersj6+qI8+skODIcz9/cUazbLbTk/ZCN
     ZelAz/20J69ifj4AAYaUlV2LsoOIcYP05+pTPBlL5SGYvTGBGFre8RJLgksQ02LvLlQDP/qk4KDKwQ
     Op6+7YM8mF/889f6Cyrs8xlT5tM2Rk2hNp3a
    X-Feedback-ID:                 1528665:9UZQSDSRl/NPaUcYTCjD6QDsisD+i+sNMgmjc0Vjua0=:9UZQSDSRl/NPaUcYTCjD6QDsisD        +i+sNMgmjc0Vjua0=:SG
    List-Unsubscribe: <https://u1528665.ct.ssss.net/wf/unsubscribe?                        upn=UbjGPFuTTwKzcR8eB-2FuGsc0qQAY3Hft5f-2BlmZfUg-                        2FJw8vhmMxAV6OxUdoN2WJkTdVTfwKMkfCLAmTQUCan6W4oSXrF1gt0cNb2-                2BSzCxrZ1KpTWQjG9NZY3MuLB5p39StmawZs4RzAnbqX46g76iqleMHqOrRIY5SLuBVsXJ2qn7ZQS5g2        04CuRhjOwb0uqcJMdGYLro0Z4FqSi8AUTzfmh4TlbaoZA9Qs34uOW2aBYY-3D>,                 <mailto:unsubscribe@sss.me?        subject=https://u1528665.ct.ssss.net/wf/unsubscribe*q*upn=UbjGPFuTTwKzcR8eB-        2FuGsc0qQAY3Hft5f-2BlmZfUg-                2FJw8vhmMxAV6OxUdoN2WJkTdVTfwKMkfCLAmTQUCan6W4oSXrF1gt0cNb2-                2BSzCxrZ1KpTWQjG9NZY3MuLB5p39StmawZs4RzAnbqX46g76iqleMHqOrRIY5SLuBVsXJ2qn7ZQS5g2        04CuRhjOwb0uqcJMdGYLro0Z4FqSi8AUTzfmh4TlbaoZA9Qs34uOW2aBYY-3D>

    BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
    VERSION:2.0
    CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
    METHOD:CANCEL
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTSTART:20150304T133000Z
    DTEND:20150304T143000Z
    DTSTAMP:20150216T212734Z
                                ORGANIZER;CN=Servexia:mailto:72fiic4ab8q2q3tm0c83snepso@group.calendar.google.com
    UID:4802a399-8631-45f7-966c-9c02f73be185
    ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-        ACTION;CN=Lu igi Lenguito;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:nicola@gmail.com
    ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-        ACTION;CN=fa bio@gmail.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:fabio@gmail.com
    ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-        ACTION;CN=A drea De Prova;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:Pippo@gmail.com
    ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-        ACTION;CN=fabio@gmail.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:fabio@gmail.com
    CREATED:20150211T150114Z
    DESCRIPTION:
    LAST-MODIFIED:20150216T212734Z
    LOCATION:Cap Omega
    SEQUENCE:1
    STATUS:CANCELLED
    SUMMARY:RDV - Cap Omega - Romain Lotou
    TRANSP:OPAQUE
    END:VEVENT
    END:VCALENDAR
```

**code asp for send the**

```
Dim iMsg
Dim iConf
Dim Flds
Dim strHTML
Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1
set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set Flds = iConf.Fields
dim sch : sch = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
With Flds
 .Item(sch & "sendusing") = 2
 .Item(sch & "smtpserver") = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
 .Item(sch & "smtpserverport") =465
 .Item(sch & "smtpconnectiontimeout") = 10
 .item(sch & "smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic auth
 .item(sch & "smtpusessl") = True
 .item(sch & "sendusername") = "ssssssssssssss@azure.com"
     .item(sch & "sendpassword") = "sssssssssss"
 .Update
End With
' Build HTML for message body.


dest="prova@gmail.com"

testo=cstr(code &"-" & instcode & " " & tidyxml(gdescription) & " http://www.numero-telefono.it/?id="& instid)

mailhtml=MailTemplate(testo)

Dim iBP
With iMsg
 Set .Configuration = iConf
 .To = dest

if bcc <> "" then
.bcc =bcc
end if

if cc <> "" then
.cc =cc
end if

 .From = "info@prova.com"


if repley <> "" then
    .ReplyTo = repley
end if

 .Subject = title
 .HTMLBody =mailhtml 

 .AddAttachment (server.mappath("icalDemo.ics"))

 .Send
End With
' Clean up variables.
Set iBP = Nothing
Set iMsg = Nothing
Set iConf = Nothing
Set Flds = Nothing
```

Comment: Could you show some code please

Comment: I meant the asp/vbs code you use to add the attachment to your cdo.message object

Comment: I confirm that the problem has to be some way to attach.
because if I send the message by attaching it to an email client to myself I get the preview of google calendar but if the same file from asp I am attaching it appears only the message that the email contains an invitation

Comment: OK bit of a guess here. On the line underneath `.HTMLBody =mailhtml ` try adding `.BodyPart.ContentMediaType = "multipart/mixed"`

Comment: Thanks John, but nothing has changed.

Comment: You could also try adding either `.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:content-type") = "multipart/mixed" ` or `.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:content-type") = "multipart/alternative"` to your set of iconf.Fields.  I think there's a good chance that content type is the key to solving this

Comment: Thank you John for the tips, but after many trials I have not found a solution.
then not understanding what it could be, I loaded the same files on two other servers, on Aruba (Italy) and on Godaddy.
Currently I was working on Azure.
I have the same behavior on aruba azure while sending from Godaddy everything works properly. I do not know what changed since the file on Godaddy and Azure are identical.

Comment: Are you using `smtp.sendgrid.net` as your smtp server with Godaddy too.  If you're not then that could be the difference.